# Sencha touche form validation

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I am creating my first app with sencha touch.
I have a problem with form validation.
This is the form:

```
var form = new Ext.form.FormPanel({
        title: 'Activity',
        items: [{
            xtype: 'fieldset',
            items: [{
                xtype: 'textfield',
                name : 'sector',
                label: 'Sector',
                required: true
            },
            {
                xtype: 'selectfield',
                name : 'city',
                label: 'City',
                options: [
                {
                    text: '*',
                    value: '*'
                },
                {
                    text: 'First Option',  
                    value: 'first'
                },
                {
                    text: 'Second Option', 
                    value: 'second'
                },
                {
                    text: 'Third Option',  
                    value: 'third'
                }]
            },
            {
                xtype: 'textfield',
                name : 'nation',
                label: 'Nation',
                required: true
            },
            {
                xtype: 'toolbar',
                docked: 'bottom',
                layout: {
                    pack: 'center'
                },
                items: [{
                    xtype: 'button',
                    text: 'Cerca',
                    handler: function() {
                        formSettori.submit({
                            url: 'book.php',
                            method: 'GET',
                            success: function() {
                                Ext.Msg.alert('OK');
                            },
                            failure: function() {
                                Ext.Msg.alert('NO');
                            }
                        });
                    }
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'button',
                    text: 'Reset',
                    handler: function() {
                        form.reset();
                    }
                }]
            }]
        }]
    });
```

the form has only three fields:
-activities
-city​​
-nation

all fields are required.
activities and the nation must not be empty, while the city should not be equal to *

how do I control the fields?
thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There is not built in way to do form validation. You must do it yourself.

The easiest way is to use the private Ext.form.Panel method [getFields](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.form.Panel-method-getFields) to loop through each of the fields and ensure they are not empty.

```
var fields = form.getFields(),
    field, name, isEmpty;

for (name in fields) {
    field = fields[name];
    isEmpty = (!field.getValue() || field.getValue() == "");

    if (isEmpty) {
        field.addCls('x-invalid');
    } else {
        field.removeCls('x-invalid');
    }
}
```

If the field is empty, then we add the `x-invalid` class (so you can style it).